# RxJS Observable.ajax post complex object to MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rxjs, observable

I have a problem post complex object with rxjs observable ajax.

```
updateCashDesck():Observable<SomeModel>{
    return Observable.ajax({
        body: {id:5,Stocks:[{WarehouseId:5,WarehouseName:"1235"}]},
        url:this._apiServerUrl,
        method:"POST"
    }).map(r=>{
        return new SomeModel(r.response);
    }).catch((e,r)=>{
        console.log(e);
        return Observable.throw(e);
    });
}
```

The problem is that. When ajax send request it set content-type as:Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 and request data post as:

```
Id:5
Stocks:[object Object]
```

So my MVC controller does not see Stocks (Stocks: count=0).

How can i change Content-Type in Observable.ajax to application/json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the implementation, you'll see that the [`serializeBody`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.4.3/src/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.ts#L271-L293) method also supports `application/json`.

However, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is [the default](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.4.3/src/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.ts#L198-L200), if `Content-Type` is not specified.

So you need to specify `application/json` explicitly:

```js
Observable.ajax({
    body: { id: 5, Stocks: [{ WarehouseId: 5, WarehouseName: "1235" }] },
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    url:this._apiServerUrl,
    method:"POST"
})
```